# Bootstrap4 scroll spy - active to parent li

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I've got bootstrap4 menu like this:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#introduction">INTRODUKTION <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Default scroll spy adds active to nav-link (a) I need to change this, becouse my active should be after nav-item (li). Can I do that ?

You can see this here:
[Example](https://www.avatec.pl/projekty/soloje/)

When I click, everything goes ok - but on scroll - active is a href.

Comment: can you add a snippet

Comment: `$('.nav-link').removeClass('active');` should remove the active class for you.

Comment: @David I don't want to remove this, I need to change active is placed. By default active is placed In a href element - I need to change placement of active class name to nav-item

Comment: @NikhilGhuse link added

Comment: @GrzegorzMiśkiewicz scrollspy is not working in your page !!

Answer (score 2):

By default `.active` class will be added to only anchor tags.

Try something like this for your requirement

```
$('[data-spy="scroll"]').on('activate.bs.scrollspy', function () {
  $(".navbar-nav .active").removeClass("active").parent().addClass("active");
})
```

Add attribute `data-spy="scroll"`

on `<div class="container">` the parent of section with `id="introduction"`

like

`<div class="container" data-spy="scroll">`

Comment: $('[data-spy="scroll"]').on('activate.bs.scrollspy', function () {
console.log('test');
});

doesn't work - no effect :-( I've try to do like this

Comment: Ok - now I'm at home ! Thank U !

Comment: I'm too quick - this is not working at all. Its making last element of menu active and that will be all. There is no event on scrolling and changes are make. Maybe this Is bug in bs4

Answer (score 1):

I found solution. I need just to add new event (cssClassChanged) - and working !

```
(function(){
    // Your base, I'm in it!
    var originalAddClassMethod = jQuery.fn.addClass;

    jQuery.fn.addClass = function(){
        // Execute the original method.
        var result = originalAddClassMethod.apply( this, arguments );

        // trigger a custom event
        jQuery(this).trigger('cssClassChanged');

        // return the original result
        return result;
    }
})();
```

and then

```
$(".nav-link").bind('cssClassChanged' , function(e) {
        $(".nav-item").each( function() {
            if( $(this).hasClass("active") == true ) {
                $(this).removeClass("active");
            }
        });

        $(this).removeClass("active").parent().addClass("active");
    });
```